# Python - How to determine number of day of week given the Weekday

Tags: python

How to determine number of day of week given the Weekday

For example,when I give input as Monday, I should get output as 1
Is there any date function that can be used instead of simply using if else statement

So far I have:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
s_day = raw_input()
print (date.weekday(s_day))
```

This currently gives me an error as below:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "Main.py", line 9, in 
>       a = date.weekday(s_day)
>   NameError: name 'date' is not defined

Expect the output to be 1 given input as Monday, 2 if input is Tuesday and so on.

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: Gives me error:

Comment: Add all relevant data to your question. Don't address them in comments.

Comment: Gives error: > Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Main.py", line 9, in 
    a = date.weekday(s_day)
NameError: name 'date' is not defined

Comment: Import date first: `from datetime import date`, and if you want 6 for Saturday use `date.isoweekday()`. `date.weekday()` will give 5 for Saturday.

Comment: @user2332713: Where do you expect `date` to come from? Programming isn't a guessing game. Please try to understand the error.

Comment: @Matthias it was a typo. I deleted it. I'm aware how loops work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [calendar](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html) built-in library, you can handle it like this:

```
import calendar

s_day = raw_input()
days = list(calendar.day_name)

# days.index('Saturday') will print 5
print days.index(s_day)
```

Like this, the raw input must be in the correct format. Such as `'Monday'` not `'MOnday'`

Answer (score 1):

In Python3:

```
import calendar
s_day = input()
list(calendar.day_name).index(s_day) + 1
```

Over here just type the weekday name e.g. Saturday, Sunday and it will give you an integer in return.

However, Monday is 0 and Sunday is 6. So in this code Monday will be 1 and Sunday will be 7.

If you want Sunday to be 0 and Saturday to be 6 then use the following code:

```
((list(calendar.day_name).index(s_day)) + 1) % 7
```

Comment: Thanks this works :)

Comment: You're welcome. If you liked the answer please accept it and also give a thumbs up. :)